# Selenium webdriver chrome проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Как в Selenium WebDriver поменять кодировку страницы? Сайт немного поменялся и проблема появилась
Я использовал следующие флаги:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
```

Результат (скриншот, получаемый методом  brw.save_screenshot):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"

brw = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
try:
    brw.get('http://oge.fipi.ru/os/xmodules/qprint/openlogin.php?proj=DE0E276E497AB3784C3FC4CC20248DC0')

    brw.save_screenshot('123.png')
except:
    raise Exception
finally:
    brw.close()
```

приводит к этой проблеме, результат (файл 123.png):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2:

```
fc-list Arial
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Курсив,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Italic,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf: Arial:style=Обычный,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf: Arial:style=Полужирный,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Bold,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Полужирный Курсив,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Bold Italic,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf: Arial:style=Полужирный Курсив,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Bold Italic,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf: Arial:style=Полужирный,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Bold,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf: Arial:style=Курсив,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Italic,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
```

(Шрифт Arial установлен)

Comment: создайте *минимальный* пример, который проблему с кодировкой демонстрирует (к примеру, создайте index.html (`Path('index.html').write_bytes(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')`) и ручками уберите лишнее) в нужной кодировке, запустите `python3 -mhttp.server` и покажите какой *минимальный* код (с selenium) квадратики показывает. [mcve]

Comment: @jfs я добавил минимальный код

Comment: Попробовал c chrome и firefox кракозябр нет. win7. chrome=62.0.3202.94, chromedriver=2.24.417431. Такое ощущение что шрифта, который на странице сайта, нет в системе или что-то такое. Инспектор браузера утверждает что там "системный Arial"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После нескольких перезагрузок всё заработало. Всем спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Если вы видите квадратики вместо букв в `text.png`, попробуйте установить шрифты, которые поддерживают используемые символы. К примеру, `sudo pacman -S ttf-dejavu` (Arch Linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from contextlib import closing
from urllib.parse import quote as urlquote
from selenium import webdriver  # $ pip install selenium

html = '''<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Boxes issue</title>
<ol><li>abc
<li>абв
<li>\u0430\u0431\u0432
</ol>
'''
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
with closing(webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)) as browser:
    browser.get('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + urlquote(html))
    browser.save_screenshot('text.png')
```

[image: chrome page with text screenshot]

Comment: У меня под ubuntu server уже установлен этот пакет

Comment: @vladF это просто пример (поэтому сказано "к примеру"). Если код из ответа запустить, то  какой результат? Если разметку с сайта как я в комментарии к вопросу написал взять и подставить на место html, то какой результат? Если ломается, то сократите до минимального примера подобно тому как показано в ответе и обновите вопрос.

Comment: ага, Ваш пример работает. Тогда я не знаю, в чём дело

Comment: Добавление кода страницы в этот пример так же работает правильно @jfs

Comment: @vladF какой результат для `python -mhttp.server`?

Answer (score -1):

**Если так**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_driver = "C:\chromedriver.exe"

brw = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver)
try:
    brw.get('http://oge.fipi.ru/os/xmodules/qprint/openlogin.php?\
    proj=DE0E276E497AB3784C3FC4CC20248DC0')

    brw.save_screenshot('123.png')
except:
    raise Exception
finally:
    brw.close()
```

## **Удача**

**Иначе**

#

## Хорошо а так ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_driver = "/chromedriver"

brw = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
    executable_path=chrome_driver)
try:
    brw.get('http://oge.fipi.ru/os/xmodules/qprint/openlogin.php?\
        proj=DE0E276E497AB3784C3FC4CC20248DC0')

    brw.save_screenshot('123.png')
except:
    raise Exception
finally:
     brw.close()
```

Comment: Вы просто убрали использование `chrome_options`? Этот код запускается на сервере без графической оболочки и не будет работать без флагов

Comment: А у вас какая версия интерпретатора ? И OS ?

Comment: Что значит ? "Этот код запускается на сервере без графической оболочки и не будет работать без флагов"  и причём здесь chromedriver тестовое ПО для браузера googlechrome ?

Comment: ос Ubuntu server 14, python 3.6, использую headless версию хрома для создания скринов страниц, тк нет другого варианта

Comment: Так скрипт не запускается даже, просто зависает